# How to disable Azure Application Insights server request grouping?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-webapps, azure-api-apps

A couple of weeks ago, we noticed that for certain operations, the ids and values are not shown any more, and are simply grouped with [id]. This was changed by Microsoft, we did not configure this.

To be clear, this is the data shown in the table when going to Performance in Application Insights.

What Application Insights now shows is the following

```
GET Something/Get [id]
PUT Something/Update [itemId]
```

While it used to show it like this

```
GET Something/Get value1
GET Something/Get value2
PUT Something/Update 60b12ca4-b3e9-4deb-bc5a-004006b2e756
PUT Something/Update 174ad712-aa7c-4e3a-8f68-05d8ec4d989a
```

Is there a way to disable this grouping and be able to see the actual values again?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to disable this grouping and be able to see the actual values again?

No, we can't **disable** the grouping in application Insights. As per the recent [MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-request-telemetry) the Request Telemetry is collected the data with respective to the **`ID`** and **`URL`** of the execution parameter. You can group it to either **`name`** or **`source`** of the request. Instead, we can group accordingly.

*Success and failure request execution can be grouped with* **resultCode**.

You can use `request.Context.Properties["<Your custom group>"]` before adding the telemetry to Application Insights.

Make sure you have to check your code if you modified any code.

```cs
# use Request Telemetry to add the properties
telemetry.Context.Properties.Add("<Your grouped Name>", "<Your telemetry information>");
```